# Using vector of variable names in an if statement

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I'm fairly new to using R, but I've been encountering this issue a lot in what I'm trying to do. I'd like to apply a function to a specific column in a data.frame depending on the value passed to the containing function. It would look something like this:

```
myfunction <- function(var) {
        < do something to mydata$var >
}
```

Where `var` could be the name of any of the columns in `mydata` (a data.frame).

The issue is with the `dataframe$var` part of the code. I can't figure out how to dynamically call a variable name like that. `dataframe[,var]` doesn't seem to work, nor does `dataframe[,get(var)]` or `dataframe[,eval(var)]`.

I'd also like to use this same theory to loop through a vector of specific columns in `mydata`:

```
varlist <- c("var1","var2","var3")
for (var in varlist) {
    < do something to mydata$var >
}
```

But again, `mydata$var` is the problem.

Any advice or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Or try   get(dataframe[,var])

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test_frame = data.frame("a"=1:4,"b"=2:5,"c"=3:6)

varlist = c("a","c")

myfunction = function(var_name){
  return(mean(test_frame[,var_name]))
}

for (var in varlist){
  myfunction(var)
}
```

Or in a cleaner way...

```
sapply(varlist,myfunction)
  a   c 
2.5 4.5
```